# Jmeter webdriver Not recognizing CLICK Action

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to performance test page rendering of my web application, but having problem with CLICK action steps. Test is  performed on IE browser

The script is exiting out at the LOGIN. Click  step. I tried the same BY.id, still its failed.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Script was as of below:var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium);WDS.browser.get('${URL}')
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("USER")).sendKeys("test");
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id("PASSWORD")).sendKeys("test");
WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@value='LOGIN']")).click();

Comment: are you getting any error .